# Как передать token в заголовок запроса http. Есть рабочее решение на ajax, нужно перевести на андроид

Tags: java, android, ajax, http

За ранее всем Спасибо! есть рабочий код на ajax который отправляет токен в заголовок http?необходимо сделать так же только на android. Что только уже не перепробовала, ничего не выходит.Помогите пожалуйста!!
ajax : `function getStaticData(lotId) {
        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', window.appInit.csrfToken);
            },
            processData: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.site.com/.../.../.../../' + Id
        });`

попытки на android:

```
 if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            String csrf = getCsrf();
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format (params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrf.replace(" ",""));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
```

P.S Ошибки не вылетают, код работает в AsynkTask. Цель : Получить полные данные от сайта (без токена приходят не полные, а скрытые. Пример: нужно вытянуть вин код машины, результат без токена: 1HGCM56187A****** )
Может ли быть причина в том что после получения токена я по новому подключаюсь к сайту? Как тогда сохранить сессию?
Токен получаю тут :

```
 public String getCsrf(HttpClient client) {

   try {

        URL urlObj = new URL("https://www.site.com");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(false);

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

        conn.connect();

        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        String jsonstr = result.toString();

        System.out.println("CSRF_result: " + jsonstr);

        // getting csrf token
        int position = result.indexOf("csrfToken:");
        // position of token in GET response
        String token = result.substring(position+11, position + 1 + 47);
        System.out.println("CSRF_Script: " + token.replace("\"",""));

        return token;


    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("CSRFTOKEN:" +  e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: А что не так с Вашей попыткой? Неверно отсылает заголовок или падает с ошибкой или что? Логи приложить к вопросу тоже не помешает. О том, что сетевые запросы нельзя делать в главном потоке, в курсе? И `DefaultHttpClient` в Андроид давно списали со счетов. Если задача простая - можно сделать на `HttpUrlConnection`. Если посложнее, то смотрите в сторону `Retrofit/OkHttp`.

Comment: Запрос делается при помощи AsyncTask, никакие ошибки не вылетают. Просто на сайте информация приходит не полная. Пример : мне нужно достать полный вин код машины, если отправлять запрос без токена то вин приходит в таком формате : 1HGCM56187A****** , а если делать запрос с токен, то по идее должен приходить полный вин код. По крайне мере через ajax работает :( Вот поэтому у меня и есть подозрения что я как то не так передаю токен. P.S. Ответ от сайта приходит в формате json